# Multipage Control in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controls, multipage

I am working with asp.net mvc framework.
In my application I want to have a master page and multiple child pages. 
All the child pages should load if any one page gets loaded.
Say i have 4 child pages i want to have link  1 2 3 .. in the master page.
If i click on any one link the related page must be immediately available with out requesting a page to the server.

Can any one help or tell what is the best way to do it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load everything upfront with and do not show it with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Load the default view then use AJAX to bring in the rest of the pages while the user is reading the first one. That's going to get you the best performace compromise for what you're trying to do.  Loading all X pages to begin with would be very slow.